# Jupyter notebook extension of Visual studio takes longer to load and bin has some unknown files

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use Visual Studio Code and its jupyter notebook extension a lot, and in the last couple of days, jupyter notebook took significantly longer to load. Furthermore, it flooded my bin with some unknown files when I try to run the cells in the notebook.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add version of VS and Jupyter notebook extension

Comment: Both were of the latest versions(VS code -955a1aca, jupyter -v2021.8.1070546638) and I use VS code Insiders